# input text isnt responding on iphone

Tags: html, iphone, forms

I have a simple form, with simple text inputs something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="number"/>
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
</form>
```

Now when I go to the site on an iPhone, when I click into one of the text boxes it doesn't do anything at all.

However when i click on the text area it lets me start typing. So the textarea is working but not the type text input fields.

Yes this does work on a desktop PC.

I don't know why this isn't working?

Comment: have you added <!DOCTYPE HTML> at the top of this page

Comment: yes I have included that at the top just underneath my <?php session_start();?>

Comment: I am just curious how are you you calling this page , on iPhone , the URL is what I am looking for

Comment: yes url that you are typing in the browser of iphone

Comment: http://test.premiumchoiceinsurance.co.uk.php54-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/upload_portal.php

Comment: can you try commenting this style section out : <style>
        input[type=text]{
            -webkit-user-select: text;
        }
    </style>

Comment: I only put that there in the first place to try and fix this problem

Comment: ive realised when i dont link to bootstrap it works. So something in bootstrap is making this happen

Comment: refer it from a cdn and see if it works

Comment: This doesnt work either using a cdn. Something in bootstrap css is interfering

Comment: @matthewsmart If you hold down (on your iphone) to highlight text(e.g. 'Personal Details') or the text boxes themselves, it starts highlighting from from the word 'Attach' and anything above it is non-selective. Perhaps check if everything correctly works when your `@media` kicks in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div `col-lg-6 col-md-6` (Section 2) is overriding(not the technical term but oh well..), your div `col-lg-6 col-md-6` (Section 1). If you give your Section 1 div a height of 450px, you should be able to work from there.

so:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="font-size:1.2em;height: 450px;"><!-- THIS IS THE 1st section -->.....
```

You should be able to type in your textboxes.

Comment: Thank you, i managed to fix this by taking out some bootstrap line of code. But thanks anyway